# Why solving (10000 x 10000 ) linear system is slower than solving 100 linear system of size (100 x 100)

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-complexity

Why solving (10000 x 10000 ) linear system is slower than solving 100 linear system of size (100 x 100). I thought the time will be the same, but the results say something else.

I am using a linear system of equations in an application where I can use a large linear system or a set of smaller linear systems. The smaller linear systems are totally different than the larger one, meaning, the larger linear system is not divided into smaller.

Please see the following code:

```
n=10000;
NI=[  10000, 6250,  5000,  4000, 3125,  2500, 2000 1250 1000 625, 500, 400, 250 200,125, 100, 50, 40, 20, 10, 5]

t2=[]
for j=1:1:length(NI)
   t=[];       s=n/NI(j); ni=NI(j);
   for i=1:s    
     A= magic(ni);
     b= randperm(2^16,ni);
     tic; x=A/b; 
     t=[t toc];
   end
  t2=[t2 sum(t)];
end
plot(t2)
```

[Based on my machine,  please see this figure that shows the execution time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rp8v.jpg)
It is larger when a single system of size (10k x 10k) is solved and slow when we solved 2000 linear system where each one is of size (5 x 5)

**How can I prove these outcomes? Solving (k) linear system is better than solving a single larger one.**

Comment: Is not a fairer comparison solving 10,000 smaller problems?

Comment: If an algorithm for solving an $n\times n$ linear system is worse than $O(n)$ time, the single $10000\times10000$ system will be slower.

Comment: The number of floating point operations (flops) required to solve $Ax = b$ when $A$ is $n \times n$ is $O(n^3)$. So just compare the number of flops required for each of the two calculations.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I think @littleO  suggestion is enough to prove the outcomes. I have computed the FLOPS for each setup and the results match the execution time shown in the question.